# In JavaFX 8 can I provide a stylesheet from a String?

Tags: css, resources, stylesheet, embedded-resource, javafx-8

Is it possible to wrap a whole Stylesheet in a string and apply it to a certain node?
Usage case would be to add specific (non changeble) behavior for PseudoClass.
I know I can use `pane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("mycss.css").toExternalForm());`, but I would like to know if there's some way to embrd it direcly in source; something along the lines:

```
pane.getStylesheets().add(
    ".button:ok { -fx-background-color: green; }\n"+
    ".button:ko { -fx-background-color: red; }");
```

Comment: @jewelsea Indeed, I had written a new answer in September as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69234685/12643240

Comment: JavaFX 17+ now supports [loading style sheets from data uris](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8267554) which would be the preferred way to do this, as demonstrated in [Nand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69234685/12643240).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a way of doing this by defining a new URL connection:

```
private String css;

public void initialize() {
    ...
    // to be done only once.
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new StringURLStreamHandlerFactory());
    ...
}

private void updateCss(Node node) {
    // can be done multiple times.
    css = createCSS();
    node.getStylesheets().setAll("internal:"+System.nanoTime()+"stylesheet.css");
}

private class StringURLConnection extends URLConnection {
    public StringURLConnection(URL url){
        super(url);
    }

    @Override public void connect() throws IOException {}

    @Override public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new StringBufferInputStream(css);
    }
}

private class StringURLStreamHandlerFactory implements URLStreamHandlerFactory {
    URLStreamHandler streamHandler = new URLStreamHandler(){
        @Override protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            if (url.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".css")) {
                return new StringURLConnection(url);
            }
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    };
    @Override public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
        if ("internal".equals(protocol)) {
            return streamHandler;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Obviously protocol "internal" can be any (non clashing) well-formed string and (in this simple example) filepath is compeltely ignored.

I use this to set the global .css, so I do not need to remember multiple strings.
It seems the Stream is opened just once, but I do not know if this holds true in all cases.

Feel free to complicate the code as needed ;)

Credit for this method goes to Jasper Potts ([see this example](https://github.com/fxexperience/code/blob/master/FXExperienceTools/src/com/fxexperience/tools/caspianstyler/CaspianStylerMainFrame.java))

Comment: If you are writing framework level code and do not want to use up the one and only possible override of the url stream handler factory, see my answer below for a lighter weight method that will not override the static factory.  If you get an exception trying to set the stream factory, then some other code you have has already done this, and you'll need to use the internal "service loader" semantics I found in the source of the URL class.  This lets you register a handler without creating a stream factory at all.

Comment: I suppose the original poster who selected their own answer probably won't change it to the solution I left below, but for anybody who is writing a library or framework, you really, really, really shouldn't override the default url stream handler; instead, you should use the service provider framework used by the URL class itself.  Read the documentation of URL and you will see for yourself that you do not have to (and should not ever) override the default stream handler.

Comment: Java 9+ provides a more cannonical solution to this problem in the form of a subclassable `URLStreamHandlerProvider` which implements `URLStreamHandlerFactory` (so the above code can be used almost as is); this class can then be registered without the "only one call per process" issue, potential for overriding/replacing default handlers for http, jar, etc.: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/spi/URLStreamHandlerProvider.html

Answer (score 6):

Here is my CSS updater class based on ZioBytre's answer (+1 works very well).

This is a self contained class that can easily be copied to a project and used as it is.

It has a dependency on the commons IO `IOUtils` class to return a `Stream` based on a `String`. But this could easily be inlined or replaced by another library if needed.

I use this class in a project where the CSS is dynamically editable inside the application, on the server side, and pushed to the JavaFX clients. It could be used in any scenario where the CSS string does not come from a file or URL but from another source (server app, database, user input...)

It has a method to bind a string property so that the CSS changes will be automatically applied as soon as they happen.

```
/**
 * Class that handles the update of the CSS on the scene or any parent.
 *
 * Since in JavaFX, stylesheets can only be loaded from files or URLs, it implements a handler to create a magic "internal:stylesheet.css" url for our css string
 * see : https://github.com/fxexperience/code/blob/master/FXExperienceTools/src/com/fxexperience/tools/caspianstyler/CaspianStylerMainFrame.java
 * and : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704515/in-javafx-8-can-i-provide-a-stylesheet-from-a-string
 */
public class FXCSSUpdater {

    // URL Handler to create magic "internal:stylesheet.css" url for our css string
    {
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new StringURLStreamHandlerFactory());
    }

    private String css;

    private Scene scene;

    public FXCSSUpdater(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public void bindCss(StringProperty cssProperty){
        cssProperty.addListener(e -> {
            this.css = cssProperty.get();
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scene.getStylesheets().clear();
                scene.getStylesheets().add("internal:stylesheet.css");
            });
        });
    }

    public void applyCssToParent(Parent parent){
        parent.getStylesheets().clear();
        scene.getStylesheets().add("internal:stylesheet.css");
    }

    /**
     * URLConnection implementation that returns the css string property, as a stream, in the getInputStream method.
     */
    private class StringURLConnection extends URLConnection {
        public StringURLConnection(URL url){
            super(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void connect() throws IOException {}

        @Override public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return IOUtils.toInputStream(css);
        }
    }

    /**
     * URL Handler to create magic "internal:stylesheet.css" url for our css string
     */
    private class StringURLStreamHandlerFactory implements URLStreamHandlerFactory {

        URLStreamHandler streamHandler = new URLStreamHandler(){
            @Override
            protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
                if (url.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".css")) {
                    return new StringURLConnection(url);
                }
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
            if ("internal".equals(protocol)) {
                return streamHandler;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
StringProperty cssProp = new SimpleStringProperty(".root {-fx-background-color : red}");
FXCSSUpdater updater = new FXCSSUpdater(scene);
updater.bindCss(cssProp);

//new style will be applied to the scene automatically
cssProp.set(".root {-fx-background-color : green}");

//manually apply css to another node
cssUpdater.applyCssToParent(((Parent)popover.getSkin().getNode()));
```

Comment: Thanks I had about given up on ZioByte's work - which was incomplete.

Comment: Hi guys.  Look at my answer below for something that I use in production, without overriding the default URL stream handler (which can potentially screw up other dependencies).

Comment: What's `IOUtils` in your example?

Comment: @EugeneKartoyev It's a util class from Apache commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is writing framework level code that does not want to use up the one and only override of the global, static url stream factory, you can instead tie into the internal "service loader" framework in the URL class itself.

To do this, you must create a class named `Handler extends URLStreamHandler` and update the system property `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` to point to the package of that class, minus the final package suffix.  So, `com.fu.css` would set the property to com.fu, then all `css:my/path` requests would route to this handler.

I will paste the class I am using below; forgive the weird collections and supplier interfaces; you can guess what these do and replace them with standard utilities without much trouble.

```
package xapi.jre.ui.css;

import xapi.collect.X_Collect;
import xapi.collect.api.CollectionOptions;
import xapi.collect.api.StringTo;
import xapi.fu.Out1;
import xapi.io.X_IO;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

/**
 * I abhor the name of this class,
 * but it must be called "Handler" in order for java.net.URL to be able to find us.
 *
 * It sucks, but it's not our api, and it's the only way to get dynamic stylesheets in JavaFx,
 * short of overriding the url stream handler directly (and this can only be done once in a single
 * JVM, and as framework-level code, it is unacceptable to prevent clients from choosing to
 * override the stream handler themselves).
 *
 * Created by James X. Nelson (james @wetheinter.net) on 8/21/16.
 */
public class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {

    private static final StringTo<Out1<String>> dynamicFiles;
    static {
        // Ensure that we are registered as a url protocol handler for css:/path css files.
        String was = System.getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "");
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", Handler.class.getPackage().getName().replace(".css", "") +
            (was.isEmpty() ? "" : "|" + was ));
        dynamicFiles = X_Collect.newStringMap(Out1.class,
            CollectionOptions.asConcurrent(true)
                .mutable(true)
                .insertionOrdered(false)
            .build());
    }

    public static void registerStyleSheet(String path, Out1<String> contents) {
        dynamicFiles.put(path, contents);
    }

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
        final String path = u.getPath();
        final Out1<String> file = dynamicFiles.get(path);
        return new StringURLConnection(u, file);
    }

    private static class StringURLConnection extends URLConnection {
        private final Out1<String> contents;

        public StringURLConnection(URL url, Out1<String> contents){
            super(url);
            this.contents = contents;
        }

        @Override
        public void connect() throws IOException {}

        @Override public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return X_IO.toStream(contents.out1(), Charset.defaultCharset().name());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, any code can call Handler.registerStylesheet("my/path", ()->"* { -fx-css: blah }");, and you can use this stylesheet anywhere via "css:my/path".

Note that I am only looking at the path portion of the url; I intend to leverage query parameters to further increase the dynamism (by using a css factory that accepts a map of parameters), but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 3):

Since JavaFX 17 it is now possible to use data URIs.

For example,

```java
scene.getStylesheets().add("data:text/css;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("* { -fx-color: red; }".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

will simply work in JavaFX 17.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the documentation and I don’t see a built-in way to do that. [`getStylesheets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getStylesheets%28%29) is the only stylesheet-related method in `Parent`, and it only accepts “string URLs linking to the stylesheets”, not stylesheets themselves. It returns a generic [`ObservableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html), so its return value has no special methods for different types; only a generic [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29). This is consistent with [`getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) returning a [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), and `toExternalForm()` merely returning a String version of that URL object.

However, there is one thing you could try: a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Instead of passing in a generated URI to a stylesheet file, pass in a data URI whose contents are that stylesheet. I don’t know if the API would accept that kind of URI, though, given that the [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph) linked in `getStylesheets`’s documentation says

> A style sheet URL may be an absolute URL or a relative URL.

Try a really simple data URI first to see if it works. You can generate one using [this online tool](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php). If Java does accept a data URI, then you just need to wrap your CSS-containing String with some method call that converts a String to a data URI, something like this:

```
pane.getStylesheets().add(new DataURI(
    ".button:ok { -fx-background-color: green; }\n"+
    ".button:ko { -fx-background-color: red; }").toString());
```

The class `DataURI` is hypothetical. If JavaFX accepts a manually-generated data URI, then you will have to find a library that provides that `DataURI` class yourself; I’m sure one exists somewhere.

There is also a way to specify inline CSS for a certain `Node` as a `String`, which is almost what you are looking for. It is mentioned in the [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph):

> CSS styles can come from style sheets or inline styles. Style sheets are loaded from the URLs specified in the [`stylesheets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getStylesheets%28%29) variable of the Scene object. If the scene graph contains a Control, a default user agent style sheet is loaded. Inline styles are specified via the Node [`setStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setStyle%28java.lang.String%29) API. Inline styles are analogous to the `style="…"` attribute of an HTML element.

However, it sounds like it does not support selectors in the CSS, only rules – so rather than saying `.red { color: red; }`, you would only be able to write `color: red;`, and it would apply to all children of that `Node`. This doesn’t sound like what you want. So a data URI is your only hope.

---

EDIT: While this is a smart idea (I didn't know about data URIs before) it doesn't work. I have the same requirement so I tried. It doesn't raise an exception but there is a warning in the  the logs and the styles are not applied :

I used this style :

```
.root{
    -fx-font-family: "Muli";
    -fx-font-weight: lighter;
    -fx-font-size: 35pt;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-spacing: 0;
}
```

And using the provided tool generated the following data URI :

```
data:text/css;charset=utf-8,.root%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-font-family%3A%20%22Muli%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-font-weight%3A%20lighter%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-font-size%3A%2035pt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-padding%3A%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-spacing%3A%200%3B%0D%0A%7D
```

Applying it to my scene :

```
    scene.getStylesheets().add("data:text/css;charset=utf-8,.root%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-font-family%3A%20%22Muli%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-font-weight%3A%20lighter%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-font-size%3A%2035pt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-padding%3A%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-spacing%3A%200%3B%0D%0A%7D");
```

Results in (pardon my French, AVERTISSEMENT=WARNING):

```
janv. 07, 2015 12:02:03 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
AVERTISSEMENT: Resource "data:text/css;charset=utf-8,%23header%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-background-color%3A%23002D27%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-font-size%3A%2035pt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-fx-text-fill%3A%20%23fff%3B%0D%0A%7D" not found.
```

So sadly JavaFX seems not to be aware of data URIs.

Comment: Hi guys.  My answer below takes advantage of the url stream handler service provider to add support for `css:/blah` urls that map to... whatever you want, without having to override the default stream factory.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the actual question ("Java FX Stylesheet via String").:
the new JavaFX 17 CSS data URL Protocol is the way to go.

But regarding @Ajax suggestion for registering URL Protocols via Handler, here is a complete real-world example how multiple Protocols could be registered using the suggested method.

This code was written & tested on one of the oldest JDK's around.: v1.2 (1998)
Therefore bits of it are somewhat more long-winded than that for modern JDK's, but it has also been tested with JDK's 17 & 1.8 (aka. "8").

In this example, two URL Protocols are registered via a Utility Class.

So, altogether 3 Packages & 5 Classes.

**First, the Utility (includes a Test)...**

```
package com.stackoverflow.handler.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class HandlerUtil {

    private HandlerUtil() {/* Please do not instantiate. */}

    public synchronized static String register(final Class clazz) {

        final String className     = clazz.getName();
        /*
         * There must be at least one '.' in the Package Name.
         */
        final int    dotLast       = className.lastIndexOf('.');
        final int    dotLastButOne = className.lastIndexOf('.', dotLast - 1);

        System.out.println("Class Name............................: " + className);
        System.out.println("dotLast...............................: " + dotLast);
        System.out.println("dotLastButOne.........................: " + dotLastButOne);
        /*
         * Split the Package Name in two.:
         * - the part BEFORE the final '.' ("SuperPackage" Key for the Protocol Handler)
         * - the part AFTER  the final '.' (the Protocol Name, which MUST be unique)
         *   (Unique, because otherwise new URL("protocol:...") may find the Protocol in another SuperPackage)
         */
        final String ourSuperPackage;
        final String protocolName;
        try {
            ourSuperPackage = className.substring(0, dotLastButOne);
            protocolName    = className.substring(   dotLastButOne + 1, dotLast);
        }
        catch (final StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Full Classname must contain at least 2 dots. Class=" + className);
        }

        System.out.println("PROTOCOL_NAME.........................: " + protocolName);
        /*
         * Get the List of registered Handler "SuperPackages"...
         */
        final String handlerProperty    = "java.protocol.handler.pkgs";
        final char   sepBar             = '|';

        final String handlerPackageList = System.getProperty(handlerProperty, "").trim();
        /*
         * Precede & append '|' to both List & New Entry to facilitate Pre-Existence check...
         */
        final String sepListSep         = sepBar + handlerPackageList + sepBar;
        final String sepNewSep          = sepBar + ourSuperPackage    + sepBar;
        /*
         * Only append our "SuperPackage" Name to the List if it's not already present...
         */
        if (sepListSep.indexOf(sepNewSep) < 0) {

            final String updatedList;

            if (handlerPackageList.length() == 0) {
                updatedList =                                   ourSuperPackage;
            } else {
                updatedList = handlerPackageList  +  sepBar  +  ourSuperPackage;
            }
            System.out.println("Updated handlerPackageList............: " + updatedList);
            System.setProperty(handlerProperty,                             updatedList);
        }
        return protocolName;
    }

    public  static void main(final String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        testProtocol(com.stackoverflow.handler.reverse.Handler.PROTOCOL_NAME, "path/reverseme");
        testProtocol(com.stackoverflow.handler.dubble .Handler.PROTOCOL_NAME, "path/doubleme");
        testProtocol("unregisteredProtocol",                                  "path/unregistered");
    }

    private static void testProtocol(final String protocol, final String path) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        
        final URLConnection urlConnection  = new URL(protocol + ':' + path).openConnection();
        ;                   urlConnection.connect();

        System.out.println("[main] urlConnection..................: " + urlConnection.getClass());
        System.out.println("[main] urlInputStream.................: " + new String(readBytes(urlConnection)));
    }

    private static byte[] readBytes(final URLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException {

        final byte[] bytes     = new byte[8192];
        final int    byteCount = urlConnection.getInputStream(/* ByteArrayInputStream for our test Protocols */).read(bytes);
        final byte[] bytesCopy = new byte[byteCount];

        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, bytesCopy, 0, byteCount);

        return bytesCopy;
    }
}
```

**Now, two Classes for the 1st Protocol (URLConnection & Handler)**

```
package com.stackoverflow.handler.dubble;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public final class DoubleURLConnection extends URLConnection  {

    protected DoubleURLConnection(final URL url) {
        super(url);
        System.out.println("DublURLConnection.new.................: " + url);
    }

    public void connect() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("DublURLConnection.connect.............:");
    }
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("DublURLConnection.getInputStream......:");

        final String urlString = this.getURL().toString();

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(("DUBL_" + urlString + '_' + urlString + "_DUBL").getBytes());
    }
}
```

The Handler...

```
package com.stackoverflow.handler.dubble;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

import com.stackoverflow.handler.util.HandlerUtil;

/**
 * This Class MUST be called "Handler".
 */
public final class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {

    /**
     * Explicitly register the Protocol.<br>
     * This is not necessary if you reference the Protocol Name via
     * {@link  #PROTOCOL_NAME}.
     */
    public  static void register() {
    }
    /**
     * The Protocol Name for this Handler.<br>
     * (which, when referenced, will implicitly register the Protocol)
     */
    public  static final String PROTOCOL_NAME = HandlerUtil.register(DoubleURLConnection.class);

    protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL url) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("DUBL Handler.openConnection.(URL).....: " + url);
        System.out.println("DUBL Handler.openConnection.(Protocol): " + url.getProtocol());
//      System.out.println("DUBL Handler.openConnection.(Path)....: " + url.getPath());

        return new DoubleURLConnection(url);
    }
}
```

**Finally, two Classes for the 2nd Protocol (URLConnection & Handler)**

```
package com.stackoverflow.handler.reverse;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public final class ReverseURLConnection extends URLConnection  {

    protected ReverseURLConnection(final URL url) {
        super(url);
        System.out.println("RvrsURLConnection.new.................: " + url);
    }

    public void connect() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("RvrsURLConnection.connect.............:");
    }
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("RvrsURLConnection.getInputStream......:");

        final      StringBuffer sbd      = new StringBuffer();
        final      char[]       urlChars = this.getURL().toString().toCharArray();

        for (int i=0; i < urlChars.length ; i++) {
            sbd.insert(0, urlChars[i]);
        }
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(sbd.toString().getBytes());
    }
}
```

The Handler...

```
package com.stackoverflow.handler.reverse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

import com.stackoverflow.handler.util.HandlerUtil;

/**
 * This Class MUST be called "Handler".
 */
public final class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {

    /**
     * Explicitly register the Protocol.<br>
     * This is not necessary if you reference the Protocol Name via
     * {@link  #PROTOCOL_NAME}.
     */
    public  static void register() {
    }
    /**
     * The Protocol Name for this Handler.<br>
     * (which, when referenced, will implicitly register the Protocol)
     */
    public  static final String PROTOCOL_NAME = HandlerUtil.register(ReverseURLConnection.class);

    protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL url) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Handler.openConnection.(URL)..........: " + url);
        System.out.println("Handler.openConnection.(Protocol).....: " + url.getProtocol());
//      System.out.println("Handler.openConnection.(Path).........: " + url.getPath());

        return new ReverseURLConnection(url);
    }
}
```